# iOS mailto Link with newline (%0A) is Converted to <BR>

Tags: ios, email, safari, newline

The link below is recently failing to have line breaks when it opens in the Mail app.

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com?subject=Question&body=%0A%0A%0A----------%0AVersion: 2.0%0ABuild: 12345" id="address">support by email</a>
```

Instead, it is appearing like this in the Mail app:

```
<BR><BR><BR>----------<BR>Version: 2.0<BR>Build: 12345
```

but should appear like:

[image]

It was working in iOS 13, but now no longer.  I have noticed this same behavior with another app and similar `%0A`. It also occurs when using `%0D%0A`

The spaces are being coded to `%20` by javascript.

Has anyone else seen this or have ideas to try?

**Edit:** filed bug report FB9146675. Please consider doing the same. Only if there is emphasis on a topic will it be seen.

Comment: I’ve filed a bug report with Apple

Comment: Have the same issue. Seems to be new since iOS 14.6

Comment: it doesn't make a difference cause apple doesn't care about its users, but you're welcome to voice your displeasure here with the rest of us https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681023

Comment: Submitted bug report as well FB9203902. I encourage everyone to do the same. This behaviour is present in iOS14.7

Comment: This behaviour is present on iOS 15 beta 1. On top QR code recognition for mailto links is broken as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120481/generate-email-qr-code-with-subject-and-body-on-ios-15

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug which has apparently been fixed in iOS 15.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or something else to confirm this?

Comment: Someone posted here that the problem was solved. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681023?answerId=684526022#684526022

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with ios, there is a thread on developer forum, please check
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681023