# Generate Email QR code with subject and body on iOS 15

Tags: ios, email, qr-code, mailto, ios15

On iOS 14 I am using this format to get QR code correctly recognised and subject + body transferred to new email message: `mailto:steve@jobs.com?subject=Hello&body=11`

On iOS 15 this doesn't work.
Is there a new format to use?

[image: Action menu]
[image: Mail app]

Answer (score 0):

Problem got resolved in iOS15 beta 3